# PHP Wordpress Plugin Submit For to Self

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to submit a form from inside a plugin to self.

I have tried removing the action to keep it empty but it's not posting.

Here is the current code:

```
<?php 

...

 return '<form action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">

...

?>
```

What should I use in this case?

Comment: It's probably got something to do with the plugin being in a different folder. Have you tried `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];`?

Comment: yeah i tried is but that's going to wp-admin/post.php not the plugin file I'm using